# How to apply multiple validations on a single cell in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, validation, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have first column **Date** in my spreadsheet. I need two validations here.

1. No cell of this column (date) can be filled if the previous one is empty. For example, you cannot fill A3 if A2 is empty. For that, I wrote a simple custom validation in A3 and dragged it to 1000 rows.

   =IF(A2="",0,1)=1

This works pretty well.

2. I also want to check that the data should be a valid date. How can I do that? I tried hard but couldn't find how to apply more than one validation rules.

Comment: @pnuts, [excel] and [google-spreadsheet] have many common formulas and they work the same. And [excel] has at least 10 times more questions and the question has more chances to get the right answer with this tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=if(and(A2="", ISERROR(DATEVALUE(A2))),"true", "false")
```

Answer (score 0):

For Google sheets, use isdate formula:

`=AND(A2<>"", ISDATE(A3))`